# How to delete a PGPing result from PostgreSQL's libpq?

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

I am using the c interface to PostgreSQL, `libpq`.

If I do `PQping()` on the database, how do I free/delete the returned `PGPing` instance (to avoid memory leaks)?

Is there something like `PQclear()` but for `PGPing` instead of `PGresult`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

The [`PGPing` return value](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html) is just an enumerated value. There's nothing to free.

From `src/interfaces/libpq/libpq-fe.h`:

```
typedef enum
{
    PQPING_OK,                  /* server is accepting connections */
    PQPING_REJECT,              /* server is alive but rejecting connections */
    PQPING_NO_RESPONSE,         /* could not establish connection */
    PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT           /* connection not attempted (bad params) */
} PGPing;
```

Comment: Right! I forgot about the source. Thanks.